# get the unique values from the associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am having the array like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [catid] => 3
            [parent_id] => 1
            [catname] => Uncategorized
            [catdesc] => 
            [nleft] => 20
            [nright] => 21
            [nlevel] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [catid] => 5
            [parent_id] => 2
            [catname] => Category 2
            [catdesc] => 
            [nleft] => 7
            [nright] => 8
            [nlevel] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [catid] => 3
            [parent_id] => 1
            [catname] => Uncategorized
            [catdesc] => 
            [nleft] => 20
            [nright] => 21
            [nlevel] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [catid] => 3
            [parent_id] => 1
            [catname] => Uncategorized
            [catdesc] => 
            [nleft] => 20
            [nright] => 21
            [nlevel] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [catid] => 7
            [parent_id] => 2
            [catname] => Flower
            [catdesc] => 
            [nleft] => 11
            [nright] => 18
            [nlevel] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [catid] => 8
            [parent_id] => 7
            [catname] => Lillies
            [catdesc] => 
            [nleft] => 12
            [nright] => 13
            [nlevel] => 3
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [catid] => 10
            [parent_id] => 7
            [catname] => Jasmine
            [catdesc] => 
            [nleft] => 16
            [nright] => 17
            [nlevel] => 3
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [catid] => 7
            [parent_id] => 2
            [catname] => Flower
            [catdesc] => 
            [nleft] => 11
            [nright] => 18
            [nlevel] => 2
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [catid] => 8
            [parent_id] => 7
            [catname] => Lillies
            [catdesc] => 
            [nleft] => 12
            [nright] => 13
            [nlevel] => 3
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [catid] => 10
            [parent_id] => 7
            [catname] => Jasmine
            [catdesc] => 
            [nleft] => 16
            [nright] => 17
            [nlevel] => 3
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [catid] => 3
            [parent_id] => 1
            [catname] => Uncategorized
            [catdesc] => 
            [nleft] => 20
            [nright] => 21
            [nlevel] => 1
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [catid] => 3
            [parent_id] => 1
            [catname] => Uncategorized
            [catdesc] => 
            [nleft] => 20
            [nright] => 21
            [nlevel] => 1
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [catid] => 10
            [parent_id] => 7
            [catname] => Jasmine
            [catdesc] => 
            [nleft] => 16
            [nright] => 17
            [nlevel] => 3
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [catid] => 3
            [parent_id] => 1
            [catname] => Uncategorized
            [catdesc] => 
            [nleft] => 20
            [nright] => 21
            [nlevel] => 1
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [catid] => 8
            [parent_id] => 7
            [catname] => Lillies
            [catdesc] => 
            [nleft] => 12
            [nright] => 13
            [nlevel] => 3
        )

)
```

From this array I want to get the Unique Arrays.ie. If catId is same it needs to eliminate from the list.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using an older version:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($arr as $row) {
    $out[$row['catid']] = $row;
}
$array = array_values($out); // only required if you mind the new array being assoc
```

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you're using PHP >5.3, you could use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$catIds = array();
$myarray = array_filter($myarray, function($el) use (&$catIds) {
    if (in_array($el['catid'], $catIds)) { // if the id has already been seen
        return false; // remove it
    } else {
        $catIds[] = $el['catid']; // the id has now been seen
        return true; // but keep the first occurrence of it
    }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't ``$catIds``be passed by reference for this to work? ``$catIds`` will always be reset to an empty array otherwise. The callback function should look like ``function($el) use (&$catIds) { ... }``.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get that array from (presuming it doesn't magically appear)? If you're getting those results from a database, wouldn't it be *much* easier to limit them there? E.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cat_id, parent_id, catname FROM yourtable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for Convert Multidimentional array to Single array.

```
$out = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++) {
    $out = $rows[$i];
}
```

And you can check this by

```
print_r($out);
```